# filters in e-commerce for nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, filter, e-commerce

I am making an e-commerce website on `nodejs` (expressed) using `mongoDB`. There I am having a collection named "`productmaster`" which contains information about every product's size, price, categories, etc.

I want to add a filter for size and price range to the `webapp` on `nodejs`. Experts please suggest if any package for that is available or not and which is feasible one. If there is any manual way to apply filter using mongoose please give the reference of it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you need is search, basically something similar to Solr or Elastic Search. Try looking it up. Also, this is not a place with "Experts", just people like you and me, trying to help others and getting help when needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check for it 